# porting C# to android

Tags: c#, c++, android, porting

i'm trying to code an app that creates a spherize filter on a jpeg. i've been struggling for a while with java code that does the distortion due to bufferedimage not being supported on android. i've been given [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/displacementfilters.aspx) link that give a fisheye distortion written in C#. i'm considering porting this code to android using the ndk. i'm following [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/) link in order to set up the ndk. my question is the code i'd like to use is written in c# whereas the given link above on how to set up the ndk is giving examples written in c++/c. is this a problem? Basically what i'm asking is if i set up my dev machine with the second link will i be able to use the code in the first link? thanks. mat

Comment: Tangentially related, this may potentially be of use to you (I haven't used it, YMMV, etc.): http://mono-android.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may want to do is port it using opengl es (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/) first, and your development machine. Once you get there then getting it to the android will be easier.

Did you write this in C# using the DirectX library originally?

You may want to just use OpenGL ES from Java also (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html), depending on the performance you need.

**Update:**

If you want to port from C# to OpenGL ES you can look at this library, which I haven't used, but appears good: http://www.opentk.com/.

For porting to Java you can look at this:  http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=343

Before trying to get this on the Android, you may want to port the code to OpenGL ES first, in some language, then once you have the done, then going to Android will be considerably simpler as you will have the main part worked out already.

Comment: black hi, i'm new to android and not sure how to get around this and moreover which technologies to use. like i said i've found code in pure Java (jhlabs) that spherizes a jpeg but it's use of buffered image has stop me. The link in my fist post is written in c#, something i'm not familiar with. what i'd like to do is extract parts of that code that alters the pixels in my jpeg and then call that code from my android activity. I'm not too good with image processing so writing something from scratch in java with the distortion algorithm is a bit much for me atm.

Comment: black  could you point me in the right direction with some links on how to set my machine up with regards to porting? i'm not too sure how to integrate my app with opengl es either. the link using the ndk seems quite interesting as alot of image algorithms for image procesing i've found are witten in C or some derivative, thanks mat

Comment: @turtleboy - Which language would you like to do the initial porting in. For example, if you know C# then you could port to OpenGL ES first, in C#, then you could port that to Android. If you know C or Java better then that will impact the setup.

Comment: black Hi, I only know java really. I did a module at uni in c++ many years ago.

Comment: @turtleboy - So port it to OpenGL ES using Java, then to port to Android you just need to learn the Android specific issues, but you will know how to port your code.